# how to make this slide menu work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xj6a74jy/1/

Result: I would like to make a slideUp + slideDown menu the has multiple levels.

I'm stuck trying to get this slide menu to work and I'm not sure how about to get it to work. I've tried using "height"0px" on some css when clicked but ultimately I get back to the same problem. I can make it through the first click in making the slide menu work (meaning there is a slideUp and slideDown), but any level after that the slider just slides up and not down leaving me with no visible menu. Here is what I have:

```
$('.mobile-nav .navigation a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var t = $(this);
  var active = t.closest('li.active');
  active.children('ul,a, li.back').not(t.closest('ul')).slideUp();
  t.next('ul').slideDown();
});

.mobile-nav .navigation {background:#eee; width:250px; position:relative;}
.mobile-nav .navigation ul {margin:0; padding:0;}
.mobile-nav .navigation a {display:block; line-height:30px;}
.mobile-nav .navigation li ul {display:none;}

<div class="mobile-nav">
   <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
         <li class="active">
            <a href="#">All</a>
            <ul style="display:block;">
               <li>
                  <a href="#">Topic 1</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li class="back">Back</li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="/sometopic.aspx">Some Topic</a>
                        <ul>
                           <li class="back">Back</li>
                           <li>
                              <a href="/sometopic.aspx">Some Topic1</a>
```

((( the menu keeps getting repeated here going deeper, using the format of

  Back
- Topic 1
- Topic 1
- Topic2

with varying number of li's in each ul.

So the first ul looks like this:

```
 <div class="mobile-nav">
   <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li class="active">
           <a href="#">All</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      /* With 3 more ul's and li's in each
      <ul></ul>
      <ul></ul>
      <ul></ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

When I click on one of the a href tag's, the menu slides to the next level showing the ul, which is the 2nd ul. But when I click on any of the li a's within this ul, I can see the menu start to slide down, but at the same time, the entire ul slides up showing nothing. The ul that was opened now is display:none; even though the next ul is now showing block. I can't figure out how to keep the slides going as they were in the first click.

I can redo classes and such if there is a better way to make this happen.

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle, [here is a new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xj6a74jy/1/).

Comment: @Keith I don't quite get how do you want it to behave. 
What is supposed to happen when you click on All ? 
And what is supposed to happen if we click on a li ?

Comment: "All" is just the starter topic, no link needed here, when you click on an a tag within an li, it is suppose to slide the new ul up and slide the previous level down, showing only the next level that was clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to make this work:

```
$('.mobile-nav .navigation a').on('click',function(e){
  var t = $(this), li = t.closest('li'), ul = li.closest('ul'), a = ul.siblings('a');
  if(li.hasClass('back')) {
    e.preventDefault();
   //do back code here
    var sib = ul.closest('li').siblings('li');
    a = ul.parents('ul').eq(0).siblings('a');
    ul.slideUp();
    sib.add(a).slideDown();
  } else if(t.siblings().length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    li.siblings('li').add(a).slideUp();
    t.next('ul').slideDown();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddled something for you: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwqs4s9b/6/)

Hope this is what you need. Just changed the way of selecting the elements.

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";

$('.mobile-nav')
    .on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        var $cTarget = $(e.currentTarget),
            $dropdown = $cTarget.next('ul'),
            $parentUl = $cTarget.closest('ul'),
            $activeElem = $parentUl.find('ul.active');

        $parentUl.children('li').each(function (key, elem) {
            var $elem = $(elem); 

            if(!$cTarget.parent('li').is($elem)) {
                $elem.slideUp();    
            }
        });

        $activeElem.toggleClass('active').slideUp();

        if (!$dropdown.is($activeElem)) {
            $dropdown.toggleClass('active').slideDown();
        } 
    })
    .on('click', '.back', function (e) {
        var $cTarget = $(e.currentTarget),
            $dropdown = $cTarget.closest('ul');

        $dropdown.toggleClass('active').slideUp();
        $cTarget.parents('li').first().siblings().slideDown();

    });})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this was a good try, and thanks for doing it, but it's not what I need. In your version the menu just slides down and keeps the other menu's open. In mine, I can only have the selected menu open, hence the slide up and slide down option

Comment: ok didn't get what you need first time. updated my fiddle and hope this is what you need. if you want to hide the all the parent li's on e.g. navigation level 2 or 3, give me a hint I will try to get this work

Comment: hmmm on the 2nd click into the menu, the page refreshes itself, so I can't see anything in your code that suggests a refresh of the page, but that seems to be happening.

Comment: can not reproduce this behaviour. may happens cause of the a href="#", since you cant switch the a to e.g. spans we could check if a href is # and do a "e.preventDefault" or set a class to check for

Answer (score 1):

So these answers are going to be pretty close to each other, but I haven't seen one that meets your "only one item can be open at a time criteria."  The JQuery is a little verbose if you want to stick with `slipeUp` and `slideDown` but here's an example of the code for handling it for the top-level unordered lists:

```
$('.toplevel > span').click(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('activeTop')) {
        $('.activeTop').removeClass('activeTop');
        $(this).parent().children('ul').slideUp();
        return;
    }
    $('.activeTop').children('ul').slideUp();
    $('.activeTop').removeClass('activeTop');
    $(this).parent().addClass('activeTop');
    $('.activeTop').children('ul').slideDown();
});
```

I replaced the a tags with spans (and cleaned up the HTML a bit) so I didn't have to deal with my demo fiddle navigating away, but [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7nrpa3hu/1/) implementing the behavior for both top- and second-level menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle, I would make your structure a little simpler like this https://jsfiddle.net/jk90pxgt/1/ and then your jQuery is only a couple of lines. You can obviously add back buttons if you would like and styling is up to you but this is just a much cleaner way to do the slide menu. Also don't use links and prevent the default, it is just extra code. Just do your click function on the LI

Here is the jQuery

```
$(".mobile-menu li").click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

New HTML Structure

```
<ul class="mobile-menu">
<li>First Item
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>First Sub-Item
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>First Sub-Item</li>
                <li>Second Sub-Item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Second Sub-Item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Second Item
     <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>First Sub-Item
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>First Sub-Item
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li>First Sub-Item</li>
                        <li>Second Sub-Item</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Second Sub-Item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Second Sub-Item</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
```

And CSS

```
.sub-menu {
    display:none;
}

li {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can make a slideToggle work, there just is a lot of menu and if I go this route there will be a lot of scrolling. Also, the a tag is tied in with a CMS so can't get rid of the a tag.